# Does anyone know the photographer?

Tags: photographer

[image: frog sand prince]

Does anyone know who the photographer who took this photo?

http://img.scoop.co.nz/stories/images/0901/a446541e53ad306416d0.jpeg

Comment: any context ? what"s the photo ?

Comment: The photo is up above in the body

Comment: yeah but it is a photo of what ? (other than someone holding a frog)

Comment: Oh does the photo not pop up?

Comment: It's a prince holding a frog who's in a small chair in black and white

Comment: @Max  I just included a link

Comment: What @Max is getting at, is would you please edit the question to make the title more descriptive or distinctive. Imagine a list of questions all titled "Who took this photo?". That's about as generic a title as you can get. Please see the Help Center page [How do I ask a good question?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "Be specific. If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."

Comment: Just based in the web address of the linked photo is is fairly obvious the photo was embedded in another page that was a news story. It would be most helpful if you were to provide a link to that story.

Comment: Never mind found it out I didn't have much details to go by cause I didn't know anything and the website has it as a photo for the playlist

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because photo identification isn't considered on topic in accordance with the help.

Answer (score 3):

The photographer is [Anthony Goicolea](http://www.anthonygoicoleastudio.com) ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Goicolea)). The photo you posted is the sixth in a series of 26 fairy tale characters (["F is for Frog Prince..."](http://anthonygoicolea.tumblr.com/post/246659404)) (See also [partial collection of the fairy tale series on Tumblr](http://ldgreenb.tumblr.com/post/267070433/fairy-tales)).

Goicolea is noted for frequently using himself as the subject for the photos (as in this photo; Goicolea is the model).